Split a Set-Cookie header with multiple cookies in react-native
I have a question exactly the same as the question here, but I use react-native and my string was saved on my local device came from axios header like this

cAxios.interceptors.response.use(
  async function (response) {

    const cookieHeaders = response.headers['set-cookie']
    await storeData('cookie', cookieHeaders)
    // code here...

    return response
  },
  function (error) {
    // code here...
  }
);

That means that I cant use the Headers Constructor as the accepted answer says.
I have a sting like this
cookie1=value, cookie2=value2; Expires=Thu, 06 Jul 2023 14:45:25 GMT; path=value5, express-token=value; path=value

same as the question mentioned, if I do string.split(', ') my string is split in 4:

cookie1=value
cookie2=value2; Expires=Thu
06 Jul 2023 14:45:25 GMT; path=value5
express-token=value; path=value

While here is my expected result:

cookie1=value
cookie2=value2; Expires=Thu, 06 Jul 2023 14:45:25 GMT; path=value5
express-token=value; path=value

is there a way to parse this to get the correct cookie values?

It is not as simple as it first looks. Take a look at https://github.com/nfriedly/set-cookie-parser, especially splitCookiesString function.
